# Firebase Firestore rules path in production

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug), I tried to debug [the path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#__name__)

When I'm using `the emulator` *locally*, the path is like `/databases/$(database)/documents/col1/doc1/col2/doc2/...`

so this `resource['__name__'][0]` will be `databases`

and `resource['__name__'][4]` will be `doc1`

for example, this `test` function will return `true` *(locally, using the emulator)*:

```
function test() {
   return string(resource['__name__'][4]).matches('doc1');
}
```

Or:

```
function test() {
   return string(resource['__name__'][0]).matches('databases');
}
```

But, when I `deploy` the rules, the `test` function becomes `false`.

Is it because the path in production is different? If so, how can I see it? is there any example for a production path..

Comment: It might be that there's a bug in the emulator.  File a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) if you think it's not behaving to spec.

Comment: @DougStevenson It works fine in the emulator, but when I deployed, the `test` function became `false`. That's why I want to make sure if the path is the same in `the emulator` and in `production`

Comment: I'm suggesting that you might be depending on behavior in the emulator that does not match what's in production.  But if you want to file a bug against the hosted service itself, you can do that through Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support